# How to activate the filtering action for a user field added to a grid

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization to the Release Time Activities screen (EP507020) where I add a user field.  This user field will contain the result of fetching the Appointment status from the Appointments screen (FS300200) based on the Appointment ID that I've also added to the Release Time Activities screen grid.

This was done so that the process grid could be filtered for appointment status that were a certain value.  The Appointment Status User field I've added contains the same attributes that the Status field contains on the Appointments screen, with the Cache extension looking as follows:

```
    #region UsrApptStatus
    public abstract class usrApptStatus : IBqlField
    {
    }

    [PXDBString(1)]
    [FSAppointment.status.ListAtrribute]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Appt Status",Enabled = false)]
    public virtual string UsrApptStatus { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

This works fine when I fetch the status as follows in a Graph extension:

```
    protected virtual void EPActivityApprove_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var epactivityapprove = (EPActivityApprove)e.Row;
        if (epactivityapprove != null)
        {
            FSxPMTimeActivity rowExt = epactivityapprove.GetExtension<FSxPMTimeActivity>();
            if (rowExt != null)
            {
                var appointmentID = rowExt.AppointmentID;

                var fsappt = (FSAppointment)PXSelect<FSAppointment,
                                            Where<FSAppointment.appointmentID, Equal<Required<FSAppointment.appointmentID>>>>.Select(Base, appointmentID);

                var epactivityapproveext = PXCache<EPActivityApprove>.GetExtension<EPActivityApproveExt>(epactivityapprove);

                epactivityapproveext.UsrApptStatus = fsappt.Status;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I go to filter the Status column, no matter what I choose from the list of options, it clears all rows.  I have no idea why this wouldn't work, but I'm sure I'm missing something.

Grid before filtering:

[image: Grid before filtering]

Filter:

[image]

Grid after filter:

[image]

Comment: Could you also share the code for the `AppointmentID` field and the `FSAppointment.status.ListAtrribute`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that changing the value in the `RowUpdated` event is interfering with the filter. If you wrote both extensions, it would help to have both custom fields in the same extension and use the `PXFormula` attribute to set the value of your status based on the `AppointmentID` field. This way you wouldn't have to rely on the event:

```cs
#region UsrApptStatus
public abstract class usrApptStatus : IBqlField
{
}

[PXDBString(1)]
[FSAppointment.status.ListAtrribute]
[PXFormula(typeof(Selector<appointmentID, FSAppointment.status>))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Appt Status",Enabled = false)]
public virtual string UsrApptStatus { get; set; }
#endregion
```

Comment: Thanks much, Markoan - One thing I added (which I overlooked) is that I needed to set the user field to PXString and NOT PXDBString.  I think that was also screwing things up.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. What you mention makes sense, if your field is not saved to the database then you need to use PX<Type> family of attributes to make sure it works as expected.